# PHP syntax error. Am i blind?

Tags: php

I have this PHP code and I am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ';' in [File Location] on line 120

The line with while($array etc etc) is line 120.

```
if($numrows != 0)
{
    do
    {
        //echo "<a href='approve.php?ref=" . $array['id'] . "'>Your '" . $array['keywords'] . "' article has been written and needs to be reviewed.</a>";
        //echo "<br />";
    } while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //While there are still rows in the SELECT query.
}
```

Ideas? I must be blind. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`} while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Should be

`} while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result));`

[do-while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

By the way, that snippet of code looks like it should probably be using a `while` loop, unless you're purposely using an old value of `$array` the first time through.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your while statement a ; is missing :) `while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result));`

Answer (score 0):

Missed a semicolon `;` at the end of `while` statement

```
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)); //<---- add semicolon here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                if($numrows != 0)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        //echo "<a href='approve.php?ref=" . $array['id'] . "'>Your '" . $array['keywords'] . "' article has been written and needs to be reviewed.</a>";
                        //echo "<br />";
                    } while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)); //While there are still rows in the SELECT query.
                }
```

you forgot the **;** after while condition